# "Unknown authorization header" while fetching google contacts using php, (zend) gdata and 2 legged oauth

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, zend-gdata, google-contacts-api

I am writing a 2 Legged OAuth app (Google Marketplace app) using zend gdata library.
I need to fetch google contacts.

Code as given below.

```
require_once 'Zend/Oauth/Consumer.php';
$oauthOptions = array(
    'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER,
    'version' => '1.0',
    'signatureMethod' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'consumerKey' => $CONSUMER_KEY,
    'consumerSecret' => $CONSUMER_SECRET
);

$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($oauthOptions);
$token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
$httpClient = $token->getHttpClient($oauthOptions);

$url = 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full';

require_once 'Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php';
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata($httpClient);

require_once 'Zend/Gdata/Query.php';
require_once 'Zend/Gdata/Feed.php';
require_once 'Zend/Gdata/App.php';

$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query($url);
try {
    $feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);
} catch(Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $ex){
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
```

I get following error:

```
Expected response code 200, got 401
Unknown authorization header
Error 401
```

HTTP headers sent on executing above code are:

```
GET /m8/feeds/contacts/default/full HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: MyCompany-MyApp-1.0 Zend_Framework_Gdata/1.11.0dev
Accept-encoding: identity
Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_consumer_key="686518909188.apps.googleusercontent.com",oauth_nonce="fc99e10f42cdb01c7f3ce1ab2775e616",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1316583946",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="hlbTvPExy4r4%2FyY1ddEsy1AJhf4%3D"
```

HTTP Response received:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unknown authorization header
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 05:45:47 GMT
Expires: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 05:45:47 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Connection: close

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unknown authorization header</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unknown authorization header</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: Is that very new or old code. Because as I read somewhere else, Google has changed some policies and ways of access.

Comment: @markus: I took code from google's site here at http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_php.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the "xoauth_requestor_id" request parameter is not being set when using 2-legged OAuth (xoauth).

I tried setting this query parameter on the HttpClient object that is passed to the Zend_Gdata_Calendar constructor:

```
$httpClient->setParameterGet('xoauth_requestor_id', $userEmail);
```

But unfortunately this clean approach didn't work. Seems that the Zend_GData_Calendar class isn't fully utilising the injected HttpClient object.

So I've resorted to extending Zend_GData_Calendar and instantiating my customised version of it instead. I've not fully tested all the functionality but here is what I have so far and it can easily be built upon:

```
/**
 * Slightly modified class which extends Zend_Gdata_Calendar. Fixes a problem with the request URI when using 2-legged
 * OAuth (xoauth). Adds on the xoauth_requestor_id query parameter.
 */
class Xoauth_Gdata_Calendar extends Zend_Gdata_Calendar {
    protected $requestorId;

    /**
     * Set the xoauth_requestor_id for requests
     *
     * @param string $requestorId
     */
    public function setRequestorId($requestorId) {
        $this->requestorId = $requestorId;
    }

    /**
     * Get the currently set xoauth_requestor_id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRequestorId() {
        return $this->requestorId;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc} extended to also include the xoauth_requestor_id query parameter in the request URI. This fixes
     * an authentication issue when using 2-legged OAuth (xoauth).
     *
     * @return string|Zend_Gdata_App_Feed
     */
    public function getCalendarListFeed() {
        $uri = self::CALENDAR_FEED_URI . '/default';
        if($this->requestorId) {
            $uri .= '?xoauth_requestor_id=' . urlencode($this->requestorId);
        }

        return parent::getFeed($uri,'Zend_Gdata_Calendar_ListFeed');
    }
}
```

Then to use this you instantiate this class rather Zend_Gdata_Calendar base class. You just need to call setRequestorId($usersEmail), for example:

```
$calendarClient = new Xoauth_Gdata_Calendar($httpClient);
$calendarClient->setRequestorId($userEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when trying to access the Calendar, so frustrating. I am using the latest download from Zen (1.11.10).

```
require_once 'Zend/Oauth/Consumer.php';
    require_once 'Zend/Gdata/Calendar.php';

    $CONSUMER_KEY = 'mydomain.com';
    $CONSUMER_SECRET = 'mysecret';
    $USER = 'user@mydomain.com';

    $oauthOptions = array(
        'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER,
        'version' => '1.0',
        'signatureMethod' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'consumerKey' => $CONSUMER_KEY,
        'consumerSecret' => $CONSUMER_SECRET
    );

    $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($oauthOptions);
    $token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
    $httpClient = $token->getHttpClient($oauthOptions);


    // Create an instance of the Calendar service
    $service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($httpClient);

    try {
        $listFeed= $service->getCalendarListFeed();
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have submitted a bug report to Zend on this matter. See [ZF-11880](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11880). Please vote for this bug to try and get its priority raised.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason the following clean approach doesn't work

```
$httpClient->setParameterGet('xoauth_requestor_id', $userEmail);
```

On Line 638 of Zend/Gdata/App.php it does the following

```
// Make sure the HTTP client object is 'clean' before making a request
// In addition to standard headers to reset via resetParameters(),
// also reset the Slug and If-Match headers
$this->_httpClient->resetParameters();
```

Because this is called for every request what you set in the client is erased.

Answer (score 0):

The `Xoauth_Gdata_Calendar` fix works.
And if you want to post an event, you'll need to override the `insertEvent()` function too.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc} extended to also include the xoauth_requestor_id query
 * parameter in the request URI. This fixes an authentication issue 
 * when using 2-legged OAuth (xoauth).
 *
 * @return string|Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry
 */

public function insertEvent($event, $uri=null) {
    if ($uri == null) {
      $uri = $this->_defaultPostUri;
      if($this->requestorId) {
          $uri .= '?xoauth_requestor_id=' . urlencode($this->requestorId);
      }
    }
    return parent::insertEntry($event, $uri, 'Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry');
}
```